# PHP alternating colors

Tags: php

```
  $dbc = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('payroll') or die (mysql_error());
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY employee_id DESC";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "
  <tr>
  <td style=\"padding-left: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; border-right: 1px solid #999;\">".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</td>
  <td style=\"text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; border-right: 1px solid #999;  padding-top: 2px ; padding-bottom: 3px ;\"><input type=\"button\" name=\"edit\" value=\"Edit\" class=\"selbtn\">&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"selbtn\"></td>
  </tr>
  ";

  }
```

I wanted to add an alternating color in the loop. what code should I add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$rowCount = 0;
$colorOne = '#ffffff';
$colorTwo = '#f3f3f3';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $rowColor = ($rowCount % 2) ? $colorOne : $colorTwo; 
        echo "<element bgcolor='$rowColor'></element>";
$rowCount++;
}
```

`Edited after @Jayrox comment.`

Comment: Running an if-then-else statement is better than defining a bunch of variables and then running an if-then-else anyways. And we definitely don't want to redefine those colors for every single row in the result.

Comment: This is how it should be done. however, like animuson mentioned, i would suggest putting the color definitions before the while loop.

Answer (score 4):

There are already a lot of solutions, but this one use only two lines of css.

You can set specific css on even and odd rows:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: +1 The only change I'd make is that I'd target the `td` elements instead of the `tr` elements (ie. `tr:nth-child(even) td`) and I'd use `background-color` instead. However, assuming that you don't need to support IE8, this is the simplest solution.

Comment: This one gets my vote. Dead easy to implement, and works completely independently of any server-side implementation. I'm suprised there were so many other suggestions!

Comment: Voted up as well. This is the most elegant solution, because it doesn't require unnecessary PHP and if you ever change your mind (like every third row gets an other color too) it is very easy to adjust with minimal CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS classes instead of inline styles. They're easier to manipulate. Then style the `.myclass_row_0` and `.myclass_row_1` in your CSS for the alternate row color as well as `.col1` and `.col2` for the column styles.

```
$c=1; // or 0 (added after deceze's comment)
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $c=1-$c; // magic!

  echo "
    <tr class=\"myclass_row_$c\">
      <td class=\"col1\">".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</td>
      <td class=\"col2\"><input type=\"button\" name=\"edit\" value=\"Edit\" class=\"selbtn\">&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"selbtn\"></td>
    </tr>
  ";
}
```

Or using inline styles:

```
$colors = array('#ffffff','#f3f3f3');
$c=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $c=1-$c;

  echo "
    <tr style=\"background-color:{$colors[$c]};\">
       <!-- tds here -->
    </tr>
  ";
}
```

Or using preset classes:

```
$styles = array('odd','even');
$c=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $c=1-$c;

  echo "
    <tr class=\"{$styles[$c]}\">
       <!-- ... -->
    </tr>
  ";
}
```

Comment: LOL, very creative magic, although I'd at least declare `$c = 0` before the loop starts. :)

Comment: Though the answer do not utilize templates, just like the rest, it can be easily transformed to template use.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I will declare an index(int) value and increment for each time through the loop.  Then do a check to see if index mod 2 = 1.  If so, then output a tr with the style that you want to apply to show an alternating row.

```
$color = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  if($color % 2 == 1){
    echo "<tr>";
  }else{
    echo "<tr class=\"altRow\">";
  }
  echo "
  <td style=\"padding-left: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; border-right: 1px solid #999;\">".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</td>
  <td style=\"text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; border-right: 1px solid #999;  padding-top: 2px ; padding-bottom: 3px ;\"><input type=\"button\" name=\"edit\" value=\"Edit\" class=\"selbtn\">&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"selbtn\"></td>
  </tr>
  ";
  $color++;
}
```

Comment: Defining a class on the table row is not a very efficient way of doing it. Most browsers have very different renderings for CSS properties on the table row. Otherwise this is a great way of doing it. P.S. `$color++` looks a lot better than `$color = $color + 1`!

Comment: Agreed, I just couldn't remember if PHP had a ++ operand (been in .NET land for awhile).  As far as style, I agree as well, IE is a pain with row styling.  Just wanted to hammer out an example of how to use the mod operation.

Answer (score 2):

As it's bumped already, here is my 5 cents.

7 answers and not a single one using templates.
We can write a thousand articles of the templates necessity, but such an examples will always win.

So, based on the OP's code and stagas' answer:

business logic part:

```
$c      = 1;
$DATA   = array();
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY employee_id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $row['c'] = $c=1-$c;
  $DATA[] = $row;
}
```

and template part:

```
<tr class="myclass_row_<?=$row['$c']?>">
  <td class="col1"><?=$row['first_name']?> <?=$row['last_name']?></td>
  <td class="col2">
    <input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" class="selbtn">&nbsp;<input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" class="selbtn">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$color = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

if($color == 1){ 
  echo "
  <tr>
  <td style=\"padding-left: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; border-right: 1px solid #999;\">".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</td>
  <td style=\"text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; border-right: 1px solid #999;  padding-top: 2px ; padding-bottom: 3px ;\"><input type=\"button\" name=\"edit\" value=\"Edit\" class=\"selbtn\">&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"selbtn\"></td>
  </tr>
  ";
$color = 2;
}
else
{
  echo "
  <tr>
  <td style=\"padding-left: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #555; border-right: 1px solid #555;\">".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</td>
  <td style=\"text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #555; border-right: 1px solid #555;  padding-top: 2px ; padding-bottom: 3px ;\"><input type=\"button\" name=\"edit\" value=\"Edit\" class=\"selbtn\">&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"selbtn\"></td>
  </tr>
  ";
  }
$color = 1;
}
```

Comment: Once color is set to 2, it never reverts back to one.  The alternating styles would not been shown after the first one.

Comment: Sweet, I think I might like your method better, seems like it would be just a smidge faster doing a direct comparsion than a modulus and addition operation.  Perhaps another SO question?? :)

Comment: This wastes a lot of extra characters that would not otherwise need to be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
// here it is in less code

<?php
 $dbc = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('payroll') or die (mysql_error());
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY employee_id DESC";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $colors = array('FFF', '000000'); // valid hex colors
  $numOfColors = sizeOf($colors); $i = 0

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $i++;if($i>$numOfColors){$i=0;}
?>

  <tr>
  <td style="padding-left: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #<?=$colors[$i]?>; border-right: 1px solid #<?=$colors[$i]?>;"> <?=$row['first_name']?> <?=$row['last_name']?> </td>
  <td style="text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #<?=$colors[$i]?>; border-right: 1px solid #<?=$colors[$i]?>;  padding-top: 2px ; padding-bottom: 3px ;"><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" class="selbtn">&nbsp;<input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" class="selbtn"></td>
  </tr>

<?php

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track whether it is an alternating row with a Boolean. Initialize it to `false` before your loop, not it for each iteration, then you can set the row style based on its value. Something like:

```
...

$isAlternatingRow = false;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "
       <tr class=\"" . $isAlternatingRow ? "defaultRow" : "alternatingRow" . "\">
       <td style=\"padding-left: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; border-right: 1px solid #999;\">".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</td>
       <td style=\"text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; border-right: 1px solid #999;  padding-top: 2px ; padding-bottom: 3px ;\"><input type=\"button\" name=\"edit\" value=\"Edit\" class=\"selbtn\">&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"selbtn\"></td>
       </tr>
       ";

    $isAlternatingRow = !($isAlternatingRow);
}
```

Then just define styles for `tr.defaultRow td` and `tr.alternatingRow td`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$class="even"
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  if($class == "even")
  {
    echo "<tr class='$class'>";
    $class="odd"
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<tr class='$class'>";
    $class="even";
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: There is already an answer pretty much exactly like this below.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

Remember to add a CSS class called "even", with styling of course.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
echo "<table id='hor-zebra'>";
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   if($i % 2 == 0)
   {
      echo "<tr class='even'>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['something'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }

   else
   {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['something'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
   $i++;
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using predefined color outside the loop.

```
$rowCount = 0;
$color = array('#ffffff','#f3f3f3');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $i = ($rowCount % 2); 
    echo "<element bgcolor='".$color["$i"]."'></element>";
    $rowCount++;
}
```